# Why is the blue line in the Balmer series sometimes not visible?

Tags: spectroscopy, hydrogen

So I've conducted an experiment to find the four visible hydrogen emission spectrum lines in the [Balmer series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_series) in a laboratory. I don't have any background in quantum physics.

When I looked through the eyepiece, I saw the red light, the pale blue light, and the purple light as shown in the picture below:
[image]

I've asked my lab instructor why couldn't I see the blue light and he said it is well-known that sometimes not all the spectrum is shown. He told me to look it up on the internet, since I didn't take the quantum physics course yet.

Can someone explain to me this phenomenon? Or at least refer me to an article which discusses this issue? The experiment revolved around Balmer series only. (It was my first spectroscopy experiment)

The setup looked like this:

It looked like this:
[image]

Edit:
These are the wavelengths I've found:
[image]

So I think the missing wavelength is actually the $410 nm$.

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: You haven't told us anything about either the instrument you used (aside from it's having an eyepiece) or the source (I'd guess a gas discharge tube, but you haven't said). How are we suppose to help?

Comment: I must admit I can't think of a well known reason why the 434nm should be missing. The short wavelength lines are generally a lot fainter than the red and cyan lines, but that would apply to the violet line at 410nm as well.

Comment: I've got two decent spectroscopes, one prism based, one diffraction grating based, and can confirm that the $410.1\:\mathrm{nm}$ line is hard to see. I use a typical gas discharge tube to produce the spectrum. It probably depends on quite a few factors like intensity of source, instrument, how well you block stray light and the state of your eyes whether you will see it or not. Maybe try again after allowing your eyes to get used to the dark, as you would looking through a telescope?

Comment: Both me and my partner were in a dark room for half an hour, and we couldn't find that single line. Our instructor couldn't find it either.

Comment: In one of my instruments I can use the diffraction grating as transparent (your set up) or reflective. For reasons I've never understood fully the reflective mode gives much stronger lines. It's partly due to reflection even in the transparent mode, that reflected light you don't get to see, of course.

Comment: The colors in reproduced spectra may appear different than when seen in the spectrometer. You might be seeing the "blue" ($434\,\mathrm{bm}$) line and not the $410\,\mathrm{nm}$ (or have you confirmed the measured wavelengths?). Two things work against the visibility of the $410\,\mathrm{nm}$ line: (a) it's a more excited state and usually has a lower population and (b) your eye has low sensitivity in that frequency range. None the less, I can generally see all four lines in both spectrometers I have available (one a glass prism and the other a diffraction grating in reflective mode).

Comment: Can you confirm which line is missing: the blue line at 434nm or the purple one (the farthest left) at 410nm?

Comment: Can we establish what the wavelength dependence of the spectroscope plus grating is? In general, unless using specialised glasses and gratings one does expect a reduced efficiency as one heads towards the UV.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking through some NIST atomic data for the Balmer Series from here: http://www.nist.gov/srd/upload/jpcrd382009565p.pdf

It lists the spontaneous emission rates for the Balmer series as follows:

- $\lambda = 656 \text{ nm}$, $A_{32} = 4.41\text{e+}7\text{ s}^{-1}$
- $\lambda = 486 \text{ nm}$, $A_{42} = 8.42\text{e+}6\text{ s}^{-1}$
- $\lambda = 434 \text{ nm}$, $A_{52} = 2.53\text{e+}6\text{ s}^{-1}$
- $\lambda = 410 \text{ nm}$, $A_{62} = 9.73\text{e+}5\text{ s}^{-1}$
- $\lambda = 397 \text{ nm}$, $A_{72} = 4.38\text{e+}5\text{ s}^{-1}$

So, the lines should certainly get dimmer as you move toward the UV, but I don't see any reason from a quantum mechanics perspective that the blue line at $\lambda = 434 \text{ nm}$ should be dimmer than the line at $\lambda = 410\text{ nm}$

Based you edit above, you seem to be missing the 410 line.  It might not be seen because 1. the spontaneous emission rate is lowered and 2. your eyes are not as sensitive in this part of the EM spectrum. 3. As dmckee pointed out in your comments section, being a higher excited state, it will also be less populated that lower lying levels, meaning the total spontaneous emission from this state will be even further decreased.

Comment: I stand corrected, the missing wavelength was $410 nm$
So the explanation is that the purple line is dimmer then the other lines? Isn't there a better answer?

Comment: @Alexs68 I edited my answer correspondingly.  Its probably do to both the lowered spontaneous emission rate and your eyes not being sensitive when you get to low wavelengths.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the blue line in the Balmer series sometimes not visible?

The human eye has difficulties in distinguishing dark blue lines on a black background.

You can use "Microsoft Word" to draw a black rectangle and a few dark blue lines of different thicknesses on the rectangle. The thinner the dark blue line the less visible it is. Even the thick dark blue lines are not quite visible.